# LoadModule mod_ssl modules/mod_ssl.so shows error message at server startup

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to add SSL module into Httpd Server. So, I created mod_ssl.so file by compiling the SSL module source code, with the help of apxs. I used command "apxs -c mod_ssl.c". I added the string "LoadModule mod_ssl modules/mod_ssl.so" into the httpd.conf file.

When I start the server I got the error message -

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 57 of /Users/gauravgoel/Apache-HttpServer/httpdBuild-2.2.16/httpdInstall-2.2.16/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Users/gauravgoel/Apache-HttpServer/httpdBuild-2.2.16/httpdInstall-2.2.16/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: dlopen(/Users/gauravgoel/Apache-HttpServer/httpdBuild-2.2.16/httpdInstall-2.2.16/modules/mod_ssl.so, 10): Symbol not found: _ssl_callback_TmpDH\n  Referenced from: /Users/gauravgoel/Apache-HttpServer/httpdBuild-2.2.16/httpdInstall-2.2.16/modules/mod_ssl.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /Users/gauravgoel/Apache-HttpServer/httpdBuild-2.2.16/httpdInstall-2.2.16/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What is the OS?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because apache cannot find the libssl.so dynamic library. On a Linux system, look at the man page for `ldconfig` and see if your openssl library in the dynamic linker path with `ldconfig -p`. On Solaris, look at the man page for `crle` to see what your runtime linker environment is.

Comment: `ldd /Users/gauravgoel/Apache-HttpServer/httpdBuild-2.2.16/httpdInstall-2.2.16/modules/mod_ssl.so` will also show more directly if any required libraries are missing.